# Use Omnifaces Validator in a composition component with the "for" tag

Tags: jsf, validation, composite-component, omnifaces

I want to use the o:validator tag from the omnifaces library for a composition component:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="disabled" />
    <cc:attribute name="label" />
    <cc:attribute name="validatorMessage" />
    <cc:attribute name="required" />
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="date" targets="textfield"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:outputLabel id="label" for="textfield" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" rendered="#{cc.attrs.label!=null}" />
    <p:inputText id="textfield" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" styleClass="dateInputField" required="#{cc.attrs.required}" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}">      
        <f:convertDateTime locale="de_DE" type="date" />
        <!-- some other stuff... -->
    </p:inputText>
    <p:watermark for="textfield" value="TT.MM.JJJJ" />  
    <cc:insertChildren/>
</cc:implementation>
```

The validator gets called like this:

```
<o:validator validatorId="customGreaterThanValidator" compareTo="#{bean.date}" validatorMessage="given date must be later than #{bean.date}" for="date"/>
```

But unfortunatly it seems that the validator tag from omnifaces ignores the "for" Attribute. With the original validator tag from JSF the "for" tag works, but not if the value of the "compareTo" tag is a ValueExpression.

I tried to implement a custom taghandler, but that didn't work either.

Comment: That was just a typo, I removed it.

Comment: This is indeed not supported in `<o:validator>`. I've created an issue ticket for you: http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=126

Comment: Hi, BalusC thanks for Answer/Ticket. I guess it will take some time, till this feature is implemented. Do you know another way I can accomplish my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed not supported in the current 1.3 `<o:validator>` (nor `<o:converter>`). It will come in future 1.4 as per [issue 126](http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=126) (where you can download the snapshot).

The key is to change `TagHandler` to [`ValidatorHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/ValidatorHandler.html) and [`ConverterHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/ConverterHandler.html) respectively so that the [`TagHandlerDelegate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/TagHandlerDelegate.html) can do its job for composites.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you. Unfortunatly, it doesn't work for me. The EL is resolved to an empty String.

Comment: I made an comment in [issue 126](http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=126).

Comment: My special case works with <c:set var="bean" value="#{someBean}" scope="request" />. So I'm accepting this as answer.